# Any ideas for how to merge a stacked switch into a single Lutron Caseta?

Tags: wiring, switch, dimmer-switch, smart-switch

Trying to install a single Lutron Caseta smart switch to combine the two parts of a stacked switch into one. Currently there are 2 lights, controlled separately by this stacked switch that I'd like to merge to be controlled by one single switch.

I've made a basic diagram below based on what I found when I opened the faceplate, but I'm not entirely sure what the colors correspond to.

I'm not sure how to safely merge these two switches into the new Lutron switch. Would appreciate any ideas.

[image: basic diagram of existing stacked switch]

[image: right side view of existing stacked switch]

[image: left side view of existing stacked switch]

[image: back of new lutron caseta switch]

Comment: The way the switch is wired, is a little puzzling. (Blue on supply side, doubled back black on device side).  Can you one at a time, disconnect each of the four wires from the switch, and tell us what lights work and do not work, in each case?  Can you also show us what connections there are inside the box, and how each of the four wires on the switch corresponds to different cables inside the box?  There are in total 5 wires on the switch.  Which ones go together to which cables?

Comment: Can you post a photo looking squarely into the back of the switch box please?

Comment: the right side of the old switch has two wires which are actually bridged on the switch. Connect one wire from the new switch to those two wires. On the left side you have 2 black and one red that are switched on/off. Connect the second wire from the new switch to those 3 wires.

Comment: I see 5 wires. One of the blacks is doubled over and goes to ??? I'm guessing 2 lights??? Or is this the always-hot supply side.  You need to figure that stuff out.  Also, this area appears to be in conduit since I see individual wire colors and stranded wires.

Comment: Re: the side with the red and black wires that appears to have 2 black wires going to the same slot – that's actually one black wire, what looks like a second black wire is just the wire end tip that they forgot to remove.

Comment: So do each of the four wires on the switch go to a conduit with a different white wire, and are those four white wires all connected together in the box?

Comment: None of the wires that connect to the switch are actually white, the ones that appear white are black with a lot of white paint on them. It looks to me like they put one hot wire on the left side, and one on the right side, which isn't correct, right? The hot wires should both be on the right side with the bridge.